# Can linearly dependent vectors span a complete set of vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Considering two dimensional space, for example $xy$-plane, typical unit vector are $\vec{e}_{x}=\{1,0\}$ and $\vec{e}_{y}=\{0,1\}$. Instead of using these vectors, can we use the vectors $\vec{e}_{1}=\{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}\}$ and $\vec{e}_{2}=\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\}$, which are not orthogonal, to express an arbitrary vector in 2-dimensional space? I just checked the answer, and it seems to say that it is possible to express an arbitrary vector in 2-dimensional space in terms of $\vec{e}_{1}$ and $\vec{e}_{2}$. Is this true?

If it's true, are there any disadvantages when using the non-orthogonal unit vectors from the practical perspective?

Comment: (1) **Any** set of vectors always spans something (this answers the title), (2) The vectors you  give are linearly **independent** and since they are two they then span the whole plane $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ . That they are orthogonal or not doesn't matter at all. (3) Disadvantages? Perhaps some in matters of simplicity, nothing really important.

Comment: @DonAntonio Many thanks for your clear answers. I have been thinking that being linearly independent means being orthogonal to each other. That is, the vectors e1 and e2 are not orthogonal, so I would like to say they are linearly dependent. Am I wrong with some point?

Comment: Yes, 58226, you are very wrong. Do yourself a favor, and look up the definition of linear independence.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Aha! I just googled and found the same question elsewhere. Now I see. Thanks!

Comment: @DonAntonio Can I say such non-orthogonal vectors exhibit the completeness?

Comment: @user58226 I'm not sure what you call "the completeness" to. In a linear space of dimension $\;n\;$ , **any** $\;n\;$ *linearly independent* vectors are basis and thus span the whole space.